Why do the solutions to the parabola in Bessel's formula gives the distances where sharp image is formed?
I had an optics lab in the previous week where we tried to measure the focal length of a lens using Bessel's method. My question is about this method.
So, in order to obtain Bessel's formula we do the following:
Assume that there is a lens in between an object and the image plane where the distance between the object and the lens is $a$ and the distance between the lens and the image plane is $b$. (I do not know how to upload an image here, so sorry about the inconvenience.)
We know the formula
$$ \frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}$$
Let the distance between the object and the image plane be $D$, then
$$a+b = D$$
and
$$ \frac{1}{f} = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{D-a}$$
By simple algebra, we obtain the polynomial
$$a^2 - aD + fD = 0$$
So the solutions to this polynomial are given by the formula
$$ a_{1,2} = \frac{D}{2} \pm \sqrt{\frac{D^2}{4}- Df} $$
So, at this point all the sources I have say that a sharp image is formed when $a$ is either of the above solutions. I want to know why is this the case. From where do we deduce this? I get the fact that the first formula and the last polynomial are equivalent. But saying that the solutions to the polynomial are places where sharp images are formed seems like one step forward.
Thanks in advance for your answers!

By the definitions of the thin lens equation, an object a distance $a$ from the lens will form a sharp image a distance $b$ from the lens.  So you're assuming that there's a sharp image formed right from the get-go.

You can think of it as down to the reversibility of light rays.
Where you had the screen you put the object and where you had the object you put the screen.
Put another way, the object distance becomes the image distance and vice versa.
Note that when $D=4f$ the object and images distances are the same, $2f$.
